# Code for repeating a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I need to repeat a macro called "DTest" for a given range in a source spreadsheet which has 390 rows. "DTest" macro creates a new Excel file and transpose pastes the range and saves the file name with value in cell "B2" in a given path.

```
Sub RepeatDTest()

    Range("1:1,2:2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    DTest
    Range("1:1,3:3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    DTest
    Range("1:1,4:4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    DTest
End Sub
```

My range includes row 1 as header, and rows from 2 to 390 as content in the new spreadsheet's row 2.

How to write a code for Range ("1:1,2:2"), Range ("1:1,3:3")....... Range ("1:1,390:390")?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub RepeatTestD()
    ' For every value of i, from 2 until 390, run the following lines of code
    For i = 2 To 390
        ' No reason to do .Select, we can perform .Copy directly on the range. 
        ' This is more precise and is also a much better coding practice.
        ' Using i as an argument in the range reference is the central piece.
        ' For i = 2, the macro will copy the range "1:1","2:2". 
        ' For i = 10, it will be "1:1", "10:10". Ad "i-finitum".
        Range("1:1", i & ":" & i).Copy
        Call DTest
    ' Go to the next value of i and go back to the start of the loop
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: So you are asking about the macro `DTest`, not how to call it?

Comment: I have a source spreadsheet with number of rows, now I would like to do the following,

# copy entire rows 1, 2.. create a new spreadsheet (new excel file) and transpose paste and save the file with value in cell “B2” of new spreadsheet.
Again
# copy entire rows 1, 3.. create a new spreadsheet (new excel file) and transpose paste and save the file with value in cell “B2” of new spreadsheet.
# copy entire rows 1, 4.. create a new spreadsheet (new excel file) and transpose paste and save the file with value in cell “B2” of new spreadsheet.

I recorded DTest macro, now I need to run for 390 rows.

Comment: Yes... if you have the macro that makes the new file and all that stuff, this macro will run it for 390 rows. Just change `Call Dtest` into `Call whateverYourMacroNameIs`

Comment: %ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "G:\DASS\3 Data\Test\" & Range("B2").Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat _
        :=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close'%


I get an error at this point for the second file while running the macro. Thanx

Comment: You should probably make a new question for that... but here are two pointers: (1) what error are you getting? (2) looks like you are trying to save several files with the same file name (value in B2)??